# Spotify curL invalid client issue

Tags: api, curl, token, spotify

I'm following the [source here](https://leerob.io/snippets/spotify), but I can't send a query with curL. I am getting an invalid client error.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic <base64 ZGQyXGNlZQY1OTUxNDc3NGJhMm.......ZTU0YDY=>" -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=code -d redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:3000 https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

According to the source, I need to get my refresh token but somehow I couldn't.

Unfortunately I couldn't do it and I would be very grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CurL query below worked

**Get the refresh token**

```
curl -d client_id=$CLIENT_ID -d client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=$CODE -d redirect_uri=$REDIRECT_URI https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

Thanks,